# Image before ul li to align with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep the image and text on the same line using css.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="latest-tweets">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="tweet-text">This is tweet Text</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhnunad/1/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`. Your css should be:

```
.latest-tweets ul li p,
.latest-tweets ul li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you have one inline element followed by a block level element then later one will start from a new line. Make both of them `inline-block` to keep them in one line.

```css
.latest-tweets ul li:before {
  content: url("https://s27.postimg.org/419bicyab/home_tweeter_icon.jpg");
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.latest-tweets ul li {
  background: none;
  list-style:none;
}

.latest-tweets ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-tweets">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="tweet-text">This is tweet Text</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Use some `max-width` on `p` so that it doesn't drop when a lot of text is added in it.

Comment: Thanks mate a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.latest-tweets ul li:before {
  content: url("https://s27.postimg.org/419bicyab/home_tweeter_icon.jpg");
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;



}

.latest-tweets ul li {

  background: none;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-tweets">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="tweet-text">This is tweet Text</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` is excess while using with `float`. `float` property makes an element a block level element so using `display: inline-block` makes no sense here. Your code will work the same way if you will remove this property.